# How to find string within a string using for loop in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to find if user input `s` contains the second user input `s1` using for loops and if statements. I only want to use methods `.charAt()` and `.length` and not `.indexOf` to find if s1 is within s. Once I find whether `s` contains `s1` or not, I either want to return `.charAt()` where `s1` begins in `s`, or return `-1` if `s1` doesn't occur at all inside `s`.

For example, `s = abcdefghi` & `s1 = def`, it will return `3`.

This is my code so far:
It either returns `0` or `-1`

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.util.Scanner;
class myStrings {
String s, s1;

void setMyStrings(String str, String str1) {
    s = str;
            s1 = str1;
}

int find() {
    int i, j;
    int r = -1;
    char ns = s1.charAt(0);
    int sp;
    int count = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (s.charAt(i) == ns) {
            sp = i;//starting point
            for (j = i+1; j < s1.length(); j++) {
                ns += 1;
                if (s.charAt(j) == ns){
                    j++;
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == s1.length())
                    r = sp;
            }
        }   
    }
    System.out.println(r);
    return r;
   }
}
public class JavaApplication5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    myStrings setS = new myStrings();

    String s, s1;

    System.out.print("Enter s:");
    s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter s1:");
    s1 = in.nextLine();

    setS.setMyStrings(s1, s1);
    setS.find();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

:D, it is because this line in your main method

```
setS.setMyStrings(s1, s1);
```

You add the same value.

Also If I look good, this line

```
for (j = i+1; j < s1.length(); j++)
```

Should be written as this :

```
for (j = i+1; j < i+1+s1.length(); j++)
```

Also this line is wrong

```
ns += 1;
```

ns is char, it means, this for example change char `A` to `B`. You need something like this  :

```
ns = s1.charAt(j-i)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to implement `String.indexOf(String)` yourself.

A place to start (or a way to cheat, depending on what your goal is) would be to look at the actual JDK implementation in class `String`: it delegates to a package-private static method which does exactly what you're trying to do:

```
static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount,
                   char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount,
                   int fromIndex) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't C, you cannot go to next char with

```
ns += 1;
```

You have to do something like:

```
if (s.charAt(j) == s1.charAt(j-sp)){
```

Comment: Even in C, this will be wrong since you didn't reinitialize ns when inner loop fail to find the string.